how can i deploy multiple endpoints to single lambda using serverless
functions:
  ptDevices:
    name: ptDevices
    handler: dist/devices/serverless.handler
    timeout: 15 
    architecture: arm64
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /devices
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /devices/connections
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /devices/contexts
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /devices/datetodate
  

How can I add all paths in one Lambda fybctuib and get exact endpoint path for each trigger respectively?
When I run this I'm getting:
/devices
 - any 
  /connections
   - any  
  /contexts
   - any 
  /datetodate
   - any

but in the Lambda function there is only one trigger for all (Trigger:https://qw735635.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/devices/contexts)
What I want:
/devices
 - any (Trigger:https://qw735635.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/devices)
  /connections
   - any  (Trigger:https://qw735635.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/devices/connections)
  /contexts
   - any (Trigger:https://qw735635.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/devices/contexts)
  /datetodate
   - any (Trigger:https://qw735635.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/devices/datetodate)

means all 4 triggers in one Lambda function.

You can add multiple functions with different name pointing to the same lambda function, each has a different endpoint. I also added a detailed answer. please have a look at this.
